# How to plot an Extreme Gradient Boosting tree built with caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, xgboost

I just built a basic classification model with package `caret` using the "xgbTree" method (Extreme Gradient Boosting).  It has great accuracy (3 classes) but I can't see the rules or plot the tree.

Does any one know how to plot the tree, when it is built with caret? I tried using the`xgb.plot.tree` function from the `xgboos`t package, but I get an error indicating it can't be plotted because my model is not an object of class `xgb.Booster` generated by the `xgb.train` function.  Is there a way I can coerce the model I built in `caret` into an `xgb.Booster` object?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `library(caret)
#Building (training) the model
tic()
myegb<-train(Confirmed.Diagnosis~.,method="xgbTree",data=training,na.action=na.pass)

names(myegb)
print(myegb$finalModel)`

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and when I looked into `?` help for `xgb.plot.tree` the first parameter is a vector of feature names and then you must specific the model parameter.

```
xgb.plot.tree(model = myegb$finalModel)
```

The above will produce the tree diagram without feature names; will use column index.

To add feature names:

```
xgb.plot.tree(feature_names = myegb$finalModel$params, model = myegb$finalModel)
```

Comment: Appending `$finalModel` to your trained model object is the key.

Comment: I do have exact same problem. Any further suggestion. @HunkyGoon did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:
xgb.plot.tree(model = myegb$finalModel,trees = tree_index)

tree_index is used to specify the index of the tree you want to plot, otherwise all the trees are going to be plot in one figure and you will lose the details. In xgb.plot.tree, index starts from 0, not 1.